# Method App\Http\Controllers\FriendshipController::assertCount does not exist

Tags: laravel

user can not send a friend request if friendship is pending

```
public function user_can_not_send_a_friend_request_if_frienship_is_pending($friend_id)
    {
        $sender = User::find(Auth::id());
        $recipient = User::find($friend_id);
        $sender->befriend($recipient);
        $sender->befriend($recipient);
        $sender->befriend($recipient);

        // return $sender;

        $this->assertCount(1,$recipient->getFriendRequests());
    }
```

but it returns me method assertcount does not exist

Comment: Should be `$this->assertEquals($expectedValue, $value)`. Also, why are you running assertions on a `Controller`? That should be in a Test class.

Comment: so I am totally wrong by doing in controller?

Comment: Yes, in your controller you will have to make an if statement and act accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assertCount() is actually a function that comes after extending `TestCase` class So it will be available only in Testcase classes that are extended from `TestCase`.

In Controllers you have to do as following:

```
if ($recipient->getFriendRequests()->count() === 1) {
    //do something here
}
```